# SQL Can't get Limit to work with group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

So I have a web server I'm practicing SQLi on my own website for personal knowledge and I can't seem to get this part figured out.

So far, I found out the table names by going to the URL below

> http://www.WEBSITE.com/about.php?id=-5+union+select+1,group_concat(table_name),3,4,5,6,7+FROM+information_schema.tables+WHERE+table_schema=database()--

Except, from what I understand, `group_concat()` only puts out a maximum of 1024 characters.

So I looked online and tried to put `LIMIT` and I didn't work. Without the Limit, I can see the name of 20 tables and half the name of table 21. So I put

> http://www.WEBSITE.com/about.php?id=-5+union+select+1,group_concat(table_name),3,4,5,6,7+FROM+information_schema.tables+WHERE+table_schema=database()+LIMIT+21,1--

And then no tables load at all. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Limit the _length_ of the `group_concat`? If so, you can't limit it's length using `LIMIT`, that's a result-set limit but you could truncate `group_concat` results or look at setting [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT` is applied *after* grouping, to the grouped results.  That is, in queries that contain a `GROUP BY` clause and therefore result in multiple groups, `LIMIT 5` would restrict the resultset to the first 5 of those groups—it doesn't in any way affect/limit the number of records that make up each group.

The reason nothing is loading at all for you is because `LIMIT 21,1` means that you want only one record starting from an offset of 21—and since  (after grouping) there probably aren't that many groups, you get an empty resultset.

You could instead fetch the table names using a subquery, limit that, and *then* group:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME) FROM (
  SELECT TABLE_NAME
  FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
  LIMIT  1, 21
) t
```

However, since `UNION` is working for you, it seems you're able to browse multiple results—in which case, why group at all?

Comment: Well I clearly didn't end up doing that right, cause the query didn't end up working when I replaced what you gave me with what I original had after the `-5`

Comment: @ILovephp123: You previously added other (dummy) columns to align the `UNION`.